# Improving function that compares two strings

Tags: optimization, c, array

I'm learning C and have made this very simple function to compare two strings. I would like to know how it can be improved:

```
int match(char* string1, char* string2)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while (string1[i] != '\0' || string2[i] != '\0') {
        if (string1[i] != string2[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I figured it will only do 2 comparisons per iteration, and 3 in the last iteration. Also, I believe it won't go beyond the end of any array because it will return before iterating beyond the null terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameters should be `const` and your loop need only to check one string for the terminator.  For example in the following loop, if `*s1` is 0 the loop stops because of the first condition. If `*s1` is not 0 but `*s2` **is** 0,  the loop stops because of the 2nd condition.

```
int match(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 && (*s1++ == *s2++)) {
         // nothing
    }
    return *s1 - *s2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` loop, you check whether `string1[i]` *or* `string2[i]` are *not* null. If they are of unequal lengths, they will have their null terminators at different values of `i`; because at least one is non-null at each point, your while loop would then continue forever. To fix this, all you have to do is change `||` to `&&`, because you need to make sure that *both* of your characters are valid.

Another improvement that I would consider would be changing the return value to be zero if they are equal; this would match the built-in `strcmp` function. Then, you could return i as the place at which the two strings diverge, also matching `strcmp`. This provides the programmer with more useful information from one function call without a loss in value, because `0` is false and everything else is true.

Comment: Don't worry, the termination works fine. If they are unequal length, the if-comparison inside the while-loop will be triggered, and return 0.

Comment: Right, I didn't consider that. In any case, it would be more readable for a `&&` operator. Also, if OP cares about performance, he should know that `&&` is short-circuiting: It will only evaluate the right operand if the left operand is true, providing some (small) performance gain.

Comment: Once you change `||` to `&&`, it no longer works correctly. When one string begins with the other, it would report them as being equal.